# Use of member of derived type in CRTP class

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have a curiously recurring template pattern class and a derived class like so:

```
template<class Derived>
class A {
  typedef typename Derived::C D;
  D x;
};
class B : public A<B> {
public:
  class C { };
};
```

This fails to compile due to B not being fully defined when the compiler attempts to define D. How can I achieve a similar result, i.e. have members of A that are of a type defined in B? Or do I have to force C to be defined outside of B?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Or do I have to force C to be defined outside of B?

Yes, unfortunately you have to do this. Usually you can define a template class before `A` and specialize it for `B`, containing the `C` type. This allows you to use it in `A`.

```
template<typename T>
struct members;

template<class Derived>
class A {
  typedef typename members<Derived>::C D;
  D x;
};

template<>
struct members<class B> {
  class C { };
};
class B : public A<B> {
public:
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and good example. Also I think a `public:` or `friend class A<B>;` is required in `members<class B>` to actually allow `A` to use `C`.

Comment: @Dylan Yeah, I meant to make `members` a struct to get the public access.